# Sqlite corruption on one database but not on another

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite database in an embedded system application. I have two sqlite databases. One database(DB1) has no issues however the other one(DB2) works fine only for a while.

The issue with DB2 is that query on the database starts failing with SQLITE_CORRUPT error. However, the write operation still keeps going on fine forever. So, the issue is that after a while or after it starts growing in size, I can not query the database anymore.

On the other hand, DB1 has no such issues. The difference between DB1 and DB2 is that the table in DB1 is created just for the float entries and the table in DB2 contains 3-4 text entries along with int entries.

I am not able to find the reason as why text entries causes the sqlite database to get corrupted.

sqlite version 3.4.5

Comment: Are you forcibly terminating the process that is manipulating the corrupted database?

Comment: No. One I detect corruption while querying the database, I don't terminate the write process.  I don't know when the corruption started. I could only know there is a corruption when I query.

Comment: Have you checked the changelogs of releases since 3.4.5 (a version not even listed in [Release History of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)), likely to have been released 8 years ago? Is it possible to upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: Yeah I could.. but I am not sure whether the issue is in sqlite or application level code.